# WebStorm indentation

Tags: webstorm, indentation

The most stupid question.

I used to have good readable code like:

```html
<div>
   <div>
      <div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then I changed something in Settings and now I don't have auto-tab, all code looks like:

```html
<div>
<div>
<div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Check that this setting is enabled.

[image]